# Transform wont rotate up or down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a movement script where I can rotate the player left and right and just rotate the neck up and down; But the neck wont rotate up nor down. For some reason, if I update the script while in game (for example, I just add `//test`), it works. Any idea why this is and how I can fix it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;

    public Transform neck;

    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            //this
            // We are grounded, so recalculate
            // move direction directly from axes
            var mousePosX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            var mousePosY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            transform.Rotate(0, mousePosX, 0);
            //Debug.Log("ABOVE - Y: " + mousePosY);
            Debug.Log("ABOVE - ROT: " + neck.rotation);
            neck.Rotate(Vector3.right, mousePosY, Space.Self);
            //Debug.Log("BELOW - Y: " + mousePosY);
            Debug.Log("BELOW - ROT: " + neck.rotation);

            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, 
                Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

            moveDirection.z *= speed * 2;
            moveDirection.x *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it out, i guess i had added some animation to the player so that overwrited the neck transform so i couldnt rotate it through script. The way i fixed this was to make a LateUpdate function where i put the rotation on the heads Y-axis, this overwrites the animation again.